# am getting an error Microsoft JScript runtime error: 'Array' is undefined

Tags: javascript, jquery, asp.net

Microsoft JScript runtime error: `'Array'` is undefined

```
var Page_Validators =  new Array(document.getElementById("rfvOthers"), document.getElementById("rfvREJECT_REASON_COMMENTS"));
```

Can Anybody Tell me what may be the solution for this

**Update**
on click of button am using the Following Function that cause the issue
it works fine in ie8 while it cause error in ie 9

```
function ClientValidation() {
    if ($("#hidTabValue").val() == "15268") {
        $("#trOthers").show();
        ValidatorEnable(document.getElementById('rfvOthers'), true);
        ValidatorEnable(document.getElementById('rfvREJECT_REASON_COMMENTS'), false);
        $("#trREJECT_REASON_OTHER").hide();
        $("#hidOther").val($("#txtOthers").val());
    }
}
```

Am Hiding the Asp.net Required field Validator on Condition basis and Face this Error

Comment: what are these document.getElementById("rfvOthers"), document.getElementById("rfvREJECT_REASON_COMMENTS")

Comment: it works fine in ie8 while it cause error in ie 9

Comment: Why not use literal notation? eg `var validators = [1,2,3];`

Comment: because its an code that will be generated by validators at the time of validating if u are using asp.net validators

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Without being able to see your screen, one can only speculate. However the code works fine here, so long as the elements actually exist.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<script>
function byId(e){return document.getElementById(e);}
function myTest()
{
    var mArray = new Array( byId('div1'), byId('mBtn') );
    alert(mArray.length);
}
</script>
</head>
        <div id='div1'>Div1</div>
        <button id='mBtn' onclick='myTest();'>click me</button>
    </body>
</html>
```

Comment: Actually am using asp.net validators and Enable and disabling the validator on the Basis of some Condition but While valiating it cause error array is undefined

Comment: Okay, gotcha. I'm not familiar with asp.net, though since it fails with one client and not another, I'd look at what the particular client says is the problem. Do you have any errors shown in the javascript debugger? If so what are it/they? (Hit F12 in IE for the debugger, in case you're not familiar with it)

Comment: var Page_Validators =  new Array(document.getElementById("rfvOthers"), document.getElementById()
Array is undefined